# Read and modify Arduino Nano 33 Iot Timer/Counter

Tags: timer, arduino, counter, arduino-nano

I'm working on a new project with my Arduino Nano 33 IoT. How can I read and modify the Arduino Timer register? I found https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/samd_timerinterrupt/ this library that enables me to use Interrupt from Hardware Timers on SAMD-based.

But I have to reset a specific timer: TC3. How can I do this? And how can I read TC3 value?

Comment: there is no universal wrapper library for the SAMD timers. open the datasheet and work with timer peripheral registers. google for examples on how to use the SDK defined register names.

Comment: `TC3->CTRLA.bit.SWRST = 1; // reset timer`